# How to Extract the src Name data scraping

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am tring to copy the name of the image only. Trying to pull it for from below code src="images/capchs/6.png" I want to copy "images/capchs/6.png" same is for Image2 and image3 as well. I am not good in the coding, someone pls help.
Thanks in advance.
from below code:

[image]

PFB my code:

```
 Sub SRC_Name()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, ws As Worksheet
Dim element As IHTMLElement
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit Data")
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate2 "" & Sheets("Home").Range("C3").text

    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend


    Dim listings As Object, listing As Object, headers(), results(), r As Long, c As Long, item As Object
    headers = Array("Img1", "Img2")
    Set listings = .document.getElementsByTagName("td")
     Dim html2 As HTMLDocument

    Set html2 = New HTMLDocument
    ReDim results(1 To listings.Length, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)
    For Each listing In listings

        r = r + 1
    On Error Resume Next



      html2.body.innerHTML = listing.outerHTML
        results(r, 1) = html2.querySelector(".cimg1").getAttribute("src")
        results(r, 2) = html2.querySelector(".cimg1").getAttribute("src")



         On Error GoTo 0


    Next
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
    ws.Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    .Quit

End With[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: If you could paste the html elements that are visible in the image above, I suppose you would get a quicker solution.

Comment: @SIM: I am able to copy the src link now, see below code... could you help me to copy next image link?

Comment: Do you have any problem pasting the html elements discarding the image above? In fact, SO discourages askers to paste image when that contains html elements. Thanks.

Comment: Cool buddy... please see my question... i just wanted to copy name of the image only:)

Answer (score 0):

I got the code guys...

```
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, ws As Worksheet
Dim element As IHTMLElement

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit Data")
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate2 "" & Sheets("Home").Range("C3").text

    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

    Dim listings As Object, listing As Object, headers(), results(), r As Long, c As Long, item As Object
    headers = Array("Width", "Length", "Hight/Space Type", "promo", "Reguler Price", "Online Price", "Listing Active", "features")
    Set listings = .document.getElementById("cimg1").getElementsByTagName("img")
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
       Set html = New HTMLDocument
    ReDim results(1 To listings.Length, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)
    For Each listing In listings

        r = r + 1

        html.body.innerHTML = listing.outerHTML
        results(r, 1) = html.querySelector("img").getAttribute("src")





        On Error GoTo 0

    Next
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
    ws.Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    .Quit
```

Comment: Now I am unable to copy next image. someone please help.